# OpenCV scalar datatype, when to use?

Tags: c++, opencv, types, type-conversion, scalar

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) we can hava a look on OpenCV's basic structures. My question is what exactly the datatype "scalar" is and when do i use it.

Here you can see its definition:

```
template<typename _Tp> class CV_EXPORTS Scalar_ : public Vec<_Tp, 4>
{
public:
//! various constructors
Scalar_();
Scalar_(_Tp v0, _Tp v1, _Tp v2=0, _Tp v3=0);
Scalar_(const CvScalar& s);
Scalar_(_Tp v0);

//! returns a scalar with all elements set to v0
static Scalar_<_Tp> all(_Tp v0);
//! conversion to the old-style CvScalar
operator CvScalar() const;

//! conversion to another data type
template<typename T2> operator Scalar_<T2>() const;

//! per-element product
Scalar_<_Tp> mul(const Scalar_<_Tp>& t, double scale=1 ) const;

// returns (v0, -v1, -v2, -v3)
Scalar_<_Tp> conj() const;

// returns true iff v1 == v2 == v3 == 0
bool isReal() const;
};

typedef Scalar_<double> Scalar;
```

Here you can see an example how they use it

```
// make a 7x7 complex matrix filled with 1+3j.
Mat M(7,7,CV_32FC2,Scalar(1,3));
// and now turn M to a 100x60 15-channel 8-bit matrix.
// The old content will be deallocated
M.create(100,60,CV_8UC(15));
```

So my question is why can't i use `double` in this case? Or arrays?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Scalar` is just for ease of use. As most of OpenCV operates on maximum 4 channel images, so `Scalar` is a simple class which is actually a `cv::Vec` of length 4, which can be used by OpenCV algorithms according to number of channels of the image. Instead of creating an array of different length each time, you just pass a scalar value to the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for a fast response

Comment: Does `scalar()` return a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [Scalar](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Scalar_) is a

> Template class for a 4-element vector derived from Vec.
>
> Being derived from Vec<*Tp, 4> , Scalar* and Scalar can be used just as typical 4-element vectors. **The type Scalar is widely used in OpenCV to pass pixel values.**

You can initialize a `Mat` also differently, like:

```
Mat img(10, 10, CV_32FC2, { 2, 3 });
```

that will be internally converted to a `Vec_`. But since the signature of the `Mat`constructor accepts a `Scalar`, you better use a `Scalar`.

This will allow to use always the `Scalar` to pass pixel values for all images with 1 to 4 channels.